# Lifetime of C++ temporary variables

Tags: c++, pointers

My question is with regards to temporary variables in C++ and how to best avoid their pitfalls.

There are instances where we do something similar to the following:

```
SomeFunctionReturningStdString().c_str();
```

where `SomeFunctionReturningStdString()` returns a `std::string` by value.

We have found however that this results in undefined behavior and have come up with two proposals to resolve this problem:

```
std::string temp = SomeFunctionReturningStdString();
temp.c_str();
```

..similar to the solution specified in this [link](http://antonym.org/2008/01/a-subtle-bug-involving-c-plus-plus-temporaries.html).

or making `SomeFunctionReturningStdString()` return a `std::string` by reference instead. In this way a temporary object should then never be created if my understanding is correct since we now have a reference to the object instead.

Are both solutions valid? Can they both avoid the pitfalls associated with temporary variables?

Comment: Your example is unfortunately simplified to the point of not being relevant anymore. Yes, there's a temporary there, but it lives long enough (full expression) so the `c_str` call itself is valid. The returned `char const*` pointer expires at the same moment (final `;`) as the temporary string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are both solutions valid?

The first one is valid.

The second one will be valid if the object to which you return the reference is alive after `SomeFunctionReturningStdString()` returns. It's not possible to tell whether that is true without looking at the code in `SomeFunctionReturningStdString()` and how the object to which it returns a reference is defined.

Unless there is a performance issue, it is better to use the first solution. It will be easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I should have been more explicit in mentioning that SomeFunctionReturningStdString() does return a reference which is valid.

Answer (score 0):

If you're receiving a returned value, it's just going to live for as long as it's in a single expression using it. In order to save it, you'd have to create some type of variable that at least has the scope of the immediately enclosing block to store it and assign the value to that variable. I hope that makes sense.